# ¿Cómo hacer el gráfico de una sumatoria?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

Tengo esta sumatoria, me piden hacer el gráfico con los primeros 40 valores de "k", cómo lo hago?
[image]

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
def graf_sf():
  for x in range(0, 16, 1):
    for k in range(1, 41, 1):
      plt.plot(x, y, color="r")
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Serie de Fourier')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Pero me devuelve un gráfico en blanco.

Comment: El código que pones no define la variable `y` que usas en el plot. Por otro lado, esa no es la forma de usar `plot()` ya que las `x` e `y` que hay que pasarle no son las de un punto, sino que ambos han de ser arrays, uno con todos los valores de las abcisas a plotear (todos los valores de t) y otro con todas las ordenadas (todos los valores de y). Debes crear una función que dado `t` te devuelva la correspondiente `y`, usando tu fórmula (internamente hará un bucle en k que se repetirá 40 veces) y usar esa función para rellenar el array `y` para cada `x`.

Comment: Cuanto vale t? Ademas no es claro si kt esta dentro del seno o sólo k

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que `t` es un valor fijo (por ejemplo, 10); la variable independiente sería `k`.

El error de tu código es que la función `plot` recibe dos arreglos de valores como entrada, por lo que `x` e `y` deberían ser los valores de los puntos a graficar.

Entonces debes construir estos arreglos previos a pasárselo a `plot`.

Esto sería algo así:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from functools import reduce
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# primeros 40 valores de k
k = np.arange(40)  # array([ 0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
#       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
#       35, 36, 37, 38, 39])

def fn(k):
    t = 10  # algun t
    return [reduce(lambda elem, acc: elem + acc, [math.sin((j + 1) * t)/(j + 1) for j in range(k_i + 1)]) for k_i in k]

y = fn(k)

plt.plot(k, y, color="r")
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Serie de Fourier')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```